# struts2 validation framework outside struts2 application

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, struts2

I have an application developed using plain jsp servlets. I want to use struts2 validation framework within this application to validate user input.
**How can i use validation framework of struts2 in application developed using pure jsp/servlet** mvc architecture.?
Please suggest.
Thanks.

Comment: Start with defining rules. Then post a code you have tried or better to get a help sooner, post [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't use S2 validation outside of S2--it's tied into the XWork framework. Why not just use Commons Validator or a newer annotation-based solution?